# Wrong date time getting extracted in my Django project

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-shell

I am currently inserting current timestamp in my postgresdb. As shown below, the date **19th feb** got inserted.

[image]

but when I got to Django shell and printed all the dates, its printing **18th feb**. How can i solve this confusion.

In my **settings.py**, current timezone is set to **UTC** and I cannot change that. Please suggest

Comment: Well since the timezone is +5, it is indeed 18th febrari for UTC.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, how can i print/retrieve it as per IST?

Answer (score 2):

The dates are actually never saved with timezone in the DB. PgAdmin just renders the data based on your local timezone. In order to set it to UTC, open a new Query Tool in PgAdmin and do:

```
SET TIMEZONE='UTC';

select * from your_table
```

Comment: Tried the way you suggested, still the same issue. 18th feb is printing